# Spacing between 3 right-aligned images looking strange in Chrome only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

Nobel Prize to anyone who can figure out what's causing this.

Firefox:

[image]

Internet Explorer:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

As you may be able to see, in the Chrome one there is a gap between the Facebook icon and LinkedIn icon, while in the other browsers they look evenly spaced.

My CSS is

```
#social-icons-holder { text-align: right; }
     #social-icons-holder > a { height: 20px; padding: 5px 10px; margin-left: 5px;}
     #social-icons-holder > a:before { content: ""; }
                            .fb-icon { background: url(assets/Footer_FB.png) no-repeat; }
                            .fb-icon:hover { background-image: url(assets/Footer_FB_Hover.png); }
                            .li-icon { background: url(assets/Footer_LinkedIn.png) no-repeat; }
                            .li-icon:hover { background-image: url(assets/Footer_LinkedIn_Hover.png); }
                            .twitter-icon { background: url(assets/Footer_Twitter.png) no-repeat; }
                            .twitter-icon:hover { background-image: url(assets/Footer_Twitter_Hover.png); }
```

and I've verified that the images are all of the same size and have the same dimensions for the white square portions of the image.

EDIT: Strange ... just tried a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4dgcnc0q/1/ and it looks fine in Chrome. Also, the images are smaller on Chrome on my webpage than they are on IE, FF and on the fiddle in Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't do anything if the code provided does not replicate the problem. There may be additional styling missing.

Comment: I know it's frowned upon to link to sites directly but go ahead and post a link and I'll check it out and see if I find another style causing the issue

Comment: I can share the link privately or if there's some way of me sharing it here without it being caught by web crawels

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem with this (not exactly this). Well, I thing that chrome and other browsers have some Preinstalled setting, that is not same in all browsers. That might be the problem. Try: open chrome > inspect element > and find ALL styling for your images. There should be some css, that browser made. Try to change them...